# c, passing struct as argument

Tags: c, struct

I need to pass some structure as function argument like this

```
void myFunc(unsigned char c);
```

I will use `myFunc(4)`, `myFunc(8)` or so.

Now the function accepts a structure as argument, so I tried

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char address;
    unsigned char command;
    unsigned char group;
    unsigned char response;
    unsigned char flags1;
    unsigned char flags2;
}test_t;

void myFunc(test_t test);

myFucn({0,0,0,0,0}); // but this gives me error
```

How can I pass const struct as argument without to have to instantiate first ?
Just like myFunc(4) as unsigned char.

Thanks

Comment: But myFunc *doesn't* accept a structure as an argument?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C99, you can use a [compound literal](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html):

```
myFunc((test_t) { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
```

Of course, since the struct is being passed by value, it doesn't matter if you consider it to be "const" or not; whatever the function does to it won't matter to the outside.

In previous versions of C, you cannot do this.

Comment: hmm... syntax error, I discovered my compiler is ANSI 89 "full featured"