# using a structura as a parameter in a function

Tags: c, function, structure

how can I use a structure as a parameter to a function? I tried this:

```
struct
{
    char name[30];
    char section[20];
    float grade;
}student[30];
```

After reading and storing the information to the structure, I called the function that writes the data into a file:

```
show(f,n,student); //n is the number of students
```

And this is the show function:

```
void show(FILE *f,int n, struct elev);
{
...
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823886/c-passing-struct-as-argument

Comment: You really should take hours to read a good C programming book.

Answer (score 2):

You'll better *name* your structure:

```
struct student_st {
  char name[30];
  char section[20];
  float grade;
};
```

Since you have *several* students, you probably want to pass a pointer to (an array of) them:

```
void show(FILE *f,int n, struct student_st* s) {
  assert (f != NULL);
  assert (s != NULL);
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    fprintf(f, "name: %s; section: %s; grade: %f\n",
            s->name, s->section, s->grade);
  };
  fflush(f);
}
```

You'll use it like:

```
#define NBSTUDENTS 30
struct student_st studarr[NBSTUDENTS];
memset (studarr, 0, sizeof(studarr));
read_students (studarr, NBSTUDENTS);
show (stdout, NBSTUDENTS, studarr);
```

Learn that [arrays are decaying into pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378555/arrays-decaying-into-pointers).